# Does a stationary process necessarily have to be mean-reverting?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stochastic-processes, stationarity

I wonder about if a stationary process is by definition mean-reverting too.

I know the formal definition of a stationary process, but I'm not sure about the definition of a mean-reverting process.

Can you provide a formal definition of a mean-reverting process and state whether one necessarily implies the other?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A stationary process does not necessarily have a mean (e.g. a process in which the random variables are i.i.d. Cauchy), and so there exist stationary processes that cannot be said to be _mean_-reverting in any sense of the word.

Comment: Thank you @DilipSarwate for the comment! could you formalize that concept in an answer? Particularly, Can you explain better what does "i.i.d. Cauchy" mean?

Comment: +1: I am unable to find a rigorous definition of a "mean-reverting process." I can't even find an unambiguous one. For instance, an authority (the [NASDAQ](http://www.nasdaq.com/investing/glossary/m/mean-reversion)) states it's "the idea that stock prices revert to a long term level. Hence, if there is a shock in prices (unexpected jump, either up or down), prices will return or revert eventually to the level before the shock." Is the return exact or probabilistic? Is the level that of the pre-shock price or a pre-shock mean? What happens when a second shock occurs before the first return?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's an interesting point of view yours too @whuber.